# Help with a weird bayesian result regarding advisors

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, bayesian, philosophy

I'm thinking about cases where you receive advice from two people who are (i) independent, and (ii) supposed to be competent on getting questions within this domain correct to a probability of >.5

Suppose, for example, that they are each .8 competent at getting questions right.

Person 1 tells you: P!

Then, Person 2 tells you: P!

Intuitively, you should become .8 confident in P after hearing from person 1. (Suppose you were entirely agnostic beforehand, with no particular view).

And, intuitively, you should become MORE confident in P after hearing from person 2.

But if you try to incorporate these two pieces of evidence by multiplying them together -- as in (0.8)*(0.8) -- then you get a LOWER confidence in proposition P than when you only had evidence from one advisor.

What gives?

Comment: The key observation is that there are only two possibilities: $P$ is true or $P$ is not true. If $P$ is true, then there's a $0.8*0.8$ chance they'll both say $P$; if $P$ is false, there's a $0.2*0.2$ change they'll both say $P$. Those are the only two events that need to be considered (the $0.2*0.8$ and $0.8*0.2$ can be ruled out because the two advisors gave the same answer).

Comment: This would make an excellent multiple choice question: Two experts' answers are independently correct with probability $p$, and they give the same answer to a particular question. What is the probability this is correct? (a) $p$; (b) $2p$; (c) $\frac{p}2$;  (d) $\sqrt{p}$; (e) $p^2$; (f) $(1-p)^2$; (g) $1-(1-p)^2$; (h) $\frac{p^2}{p^2+(1-p)^2}$; (i) $2p(1-p)$

Comment: I tried and thought it was (g). Is this right?